# Show multiple targets in showcaseview android fragments

Tags: android, showcaseview

I searched for 2 days but couldent find the answer. I want to show multiple targets in sequence in fragment by showcaseview library. Plz help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yeah I can show the showcaseview for a single target, but I cant achieve that for multiple views in sequence.